# Shell Script: How to continue the read command when no key is pressed within a case?

Tags: shell, case, pause

I'm trying to write in my script the option to enter Y/y or wait for 10 seconds (when no key is pressed) and otherwise terminating the script. For example if I'm running the script I enter Y/y and it works. It should work also if nothing is entered when I waited the 10 seconds.

So far I got it working with Y/y and also waiting for 10 seconds, but it's terminating if no key is pressed. I know it's due to my case, but I don't know how to catch the option if no key is pressed to continue the script normally.

My code so far:

```
    read -t 10 "Enter Y/y or wait 10 seconds!" -n 1 -r REPLY
    case $REPLY in
     [yY])
              echo "correct";;
      *)
              echo "Terminating";;
    esac
```

thanks:)

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. What is the desired behaviour, if no key is pressed? What is the desired behaviour if the `X` key is pressed? The `N` key?

Comment: The desired behaviour if no key is pressed is that the script continues normally. The same with Y/y. If any other key than Y/y is pressed, then it should stop.

Comment: I found that I just need to check for an empty string in addition in the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the default to be N, use:

```
read -t 10 "Enter Y/y or wait 10 seconds!" -n 1 -r REPLY
case ${REPLY:-N} in
  [yY])
    echo "correct";;
  *)
    echo "Terminating";;
esac
```

If you want the default to be "Y" use:

```
read -t 10 "Enter Y/y or wait 10 seconds!" -n 1 -r REPLY
case ${REPLY:-Y} in
  [yY])
    echo "correct";;
  *)
    echo "Terminating";;
esac
```

This code uses default values for `$REPLY`. If `$REPLY` is unset or empty, it substitutes "N" in the first version and "Y" in the second.

Comment: You can also use the fact that `read` returns 1 if the timeout hits. e.g. `if read -t 1 -p "Enter Y/y or wait 10 seconds" -n 1 -r REPLY && [[ $REPLY == [Yy] ]]; then echo YES; fi`